# Use an if statement on a Text Box

Tags: vba, excel

I am making a user entry form where they have to enter some figures. I would like them to only enter a number between 2.4 and 6. How can I do this?

My code at the moment is this:

```
Private Sub txtHeight_Change()
    HeightNumber = CStr(Val(Me.txtHeight.Value))

If HeightNumber >= 2.4 And HeightNumber <= 6 Then
    Else
        MsgBox ("You have entered an incorrect number")
End If

totcost = painttype + undercost + HeightNumber
        TotalCost.Value = totcost
End
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quoting ImClarky

Why not simply convert to double the numeric string and perform the check?

Because of the `CDbl`, an empty string will always trigger an error (especially because the Macro works for every change in the string as I understood). You can error-handle it with a `On Error Goto` the end of the Sub, or you could simply check if the string = "". In that case don't execute the Sub.

Let's say the txtHeight was a textbox

```
Private Sub txtHeight_Change()

If Not Me.txtHeight = "" Then  

    If CDbl(Me.txtHeight) >= 2.4 And CDbl(Me.txtHeight) <= 6 Then
        ' Put your code here, I think those following belong here too
        totcost = painttype + undercost + CDbl(Me.txtHeight)
        TotalCost.Value = totcost
    Else
        MsgBox ("You have entered an incorrect number")
    End If

End If    

End Sub
```

(This was NOT TESTED)

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion Noldor - anyway you can lay it out as code for me to drop in please?

Comment: Code added as requested

Comment: Thanks very much Noldor, you have fixed the problem. Thanks to @ImClarky too.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure if this will solve the problem, but the variable `HeightNumber` has been converted to a String (CStr). This then makes the operators in you `If` statement (`<=` and `>=`) not work as they don't work with String variables.

Comment: why not simply convert to double the numeric string and perform the check?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an error if it is not a string, then it throws an error (13). I need it to be a floating point really.

Comment: Does it throw the error on the line - totcost = paintcost + undercost + HeightNumber? If so it may be because the other two variables are not of the same type (err 13 type mismatch) i.e. have you used CStr(...) On the other 2 variables

Comment: @Noldor130884 - I have converted to a double now. The only problem is now, after an incorrect number is entered, and then deleted, it still throws the error?