# Stop text box from auto refreshing in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently encountering a problem. I have set up an if statement on a text box - if the number is smaller than 2.4, and larger than 6 then return an error.

However, if a user wishes to input 2.8, it will throw the error when 2 is entered, and when the '.' is entered.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub txtHeight_Change()
    HeightNumber = CDbl(Val(Me.txtHeight.Value))
    If Not Me.txtHeight = "" Then
        If HeightNumber >= 2.4 And HeightNumber <= 6 Then
        Else
            MsgBox ("You have entered an incorrect number. Please enter a number between 2.4m and 6m.")
        End If
    End If
    totcost = (HeightNumber * Width1) * (painttype + undercost)
    TotalCost.Value = totcost
End Sub
```

Comment: `HeightNumber = CDbl(Val(Me.txtHeight.Value))` goes under the If :)
You can delete the question since it is basically a duplicate :P

Comment: http://gyazo.com/2446c60bb04db8091533bb3ab81e98d9 - Still got the error!

Comment: Under the FIRST if, but over the second :)

Comment: http://gyazo.com/1967d86e93349a114ad802c79fd1e2e0 - And got the same error here...

Comment: I don't really understand the `Val(Me.txtHeight.Value)`. What is it supposed to achieve? I mean... if txtHeight is a textbox, all you need to do is CDbl it.
Plus, you didn't declare any variable, which is a really bad habit :)

Comment: Don't worry Noldor - I did. http://gyazo.com/ff73ef9e49254e99e64389504abb9519

Comment: Instead of the `Change` event that gets fired every time there's a change to the contents of the text box (i.e. for every character typed in the text box), why not use the `AfterUpdate` event that gets fired when the user leaves the control? You can do the validation at that point with the full value that the user entered.

Comment: @djikay: Sorry. Just saw your comment.

Comment: @SiddharthRout: "Stealing my thunder" but it's fine ;-) I just wanted to clarify it was what the OP wanted before posting a solution that he may not want, in case he really wants to validate input as the user types each character.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use an if statement on a Text Box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24777646/use-an-if-statement-on-a-text-box)

Comment: @djikay: I had no intention of doin git :) If you want, you can post your answer and I will delete mine :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout: It's fine, no worries.

Comment: Thank you all - All I had to do was change it from `_Change()` to `_AutoRefresh`

Comment: You mean, `_AfterUpdate`, right?

Comment: Yes - sorry. Been a long day lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `txtHeight_Change()`. Use the `_AfterUpdate()` event.

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub txtHeight_AfterUpdate()
    If Len(Trim(txtHeight.Value)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

    If HeightNumber >= 2.4 And HeightNumber <= 6 Then
        HeightNumber = CDbl(Val(txtHeight.Value))

        totcost = (HeightNumber * Width1) * (painttype + undercost)
        TotalCost.Value = totcost
    Else
        MsgBox ("You have entered an incorrect number. Please enter a number between 2.4m and 6m.")
    End If
End Sub
```